# Number of n-bit binary string with exactly 1 pair of 0s

Tags: combinatorics, recursion

Can anyone give me a non-recursive expression for the number of length-n binary strings that have exactly one pair of consecutive 0s? I have been working on this question for hours and still have no clue.

Comment: Have you gotten a recursive formula?

Comment: Nope, this question did not give us a formula, we just had to figure it out

Comment: No, I meant, have you derived a recursive formula that you can't solve?  Have you made any progress at all?  Have you worked out the answer for small values of $n$, for example?

Comment: no, I've got absolutely nothing, I don't know I just can't seem to work it out.

Comment: I posted an answer with some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have an $n-1$-bit string with exactly $k$ $0$'s, no two of which are consecutive.  We can convert this into an $n-bit$ string with exactly one pair of consecutive $0$'s by doubling any one of the $k$ $0$'s.  That is, it gives rise to $k$ strings of the sort we want to count.

So, how many $n-1$-bit strings have exactly $k$ $0$'s, with no two consecutive?  There are $n-1-k$ $1$'s, so there are $n-k$ places we can put the $0$'s and we can choose them in ${n-k\choose k}$ ways.  Therefore, there are $k{n-k\choose k}$ $n$-bit strings with exactly one pairs of consecutive $0$'s and $k+1$ $0$'s overall.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: @WhatsUp I have been staring at my computer for the last 4.5 hours straight thinking, and at the end had 0 ideas of how to tackle the problem. Just because someone is not good at something doesn't mean they have not tried.

Comment: @saulspatz thank you, I will try to come up with a solution with that

Comment: What stopped you from taking a piece of paper and trying to find the answer for (say) $n=1,2,3,4$, as saulspstz suggested in the comment? Starring at your computer... Lol what an effort.

Comment: @WhatsUp It seems to me that you are violating the "Be nice" rule of this site.

Comment: Well ok... Then what about the "show some effort" rule... I know there is a balance here and one shouldn't be too strict, but in this very post I really don't see any effort being shown.

Comment: @WhatsUp If this were a routine exercise, I wouldn't have answered the question.  It seemed to me though, that's it's a rather difficult question for a beginner, and the OP did say he'd been working on it for hours to no avail.  I did take what you are saying into account before deciding to answer.  Another thing that swayed me was that I couldn't think of a good way to put a helpful hint in a comment.  It's a judgment call.